# Rotational movement of satellite in orbit

Tags: rotational-dynamics, satellites

I would like to know how a satellite rotates around the Earth in terms of rotational movement.

If it matters I'm interested in the helio-synchronous case -where the satellite is always visible from the sun-, which I illustrate below, as seen from the sun.

Are both case 1 and case 2 both possible, without using on-board propellers ?

[image: Rotations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one is possible.

The one on the left has zero rotation.  The one on the right is rotating at the same frequency as the orbit.  In the absence of other factors, any constant rotation would be possible.

In practice, atmospheric drag tends to be significant and specific orientations are chosen where various torques are reduced over the orbit and require lower fuel expenditure to hold attitude.

Communications (antenna aiming at earth) tends to make the rotating situation on the right more common.

Space telescopes like Hubble that need to point at an object in space will be like the one on the left, holding inertial orientation for long stretches of time.

The International Space Station has orbited in both ways.  Very early in the construction it had a single solar panel that had limited movement.  During certain periods of time, it would stay pointed at the sun for power.  Now that it has movable solar panels, the station rotates to point one side at the earth during the orbit.

If you can still run flash, this [Nasa page](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/station/flash/iss_attitude.html) used to have some simulations of how the ISS orbited the earth.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. In fact, the rotation of the satellite around its own center of mass has two independent degrees of freedom, so the number of possible rotations are infinite.

There are gravitational effects that may lock the rotation of the satellite to the orbit period, but such locking takes a long time to establish. We can observe such locking in the rotation of the Earth's moon and in the planet Mercury.

Answer (score 1):

In general, homogenous gravitational fields do not excert torque free-falling rigid bodies. Therefore - at least in the first approximation - the satellite will **keep to its angular momentum**. If its spinning around the eigenvector of its moment of inertia tensor to which the greatest eigenvalue belongs, this means that it will neatly ans stably rotate around a fixed axis. So if this axis is up-down (on your picture), it follows case 1, and if it sticks out of the plane, (and has a period equal to its orbital period) case 2.

However, if it is not spinning around the aforementioned mo
st stable axis, it will eventually diverge and start to tumble.

A further complication is that Earth's gravitational field is not homogenous. This allows case 2 to be enforced using gravity gradient stabilisation (a long boom with a weight lowered into the gravity well)

But perturbations would eventually overhelm the stable attitude of case 1. Such small effects as solar radiaton pressure can slowly add up. Therefore if the satellite needs to point into the right direction in order to function, it would quite certinally need active attitude control (thrusters, flywheels or both)